# Dot or point pattern recognition for Braille Paper

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, real-time

we are very new to image processing field. 
We are gonna do a study about braille to text conversion, by the way braille is a method of writing for blind.
!(https://fryemuseum.org/images/exhibition_images/23_Jannausch_Todd.jpg)

### On our research, we find different algorithms. The procedure that we will use is first, find the edges of the braille paper using Canny Edge. But I find recently about the RANSAC. I wonder what should we use.

Another Thing is, we need to find a technique in recognizing the braille code on paper in real time using a smartphone. On our research, we think we will use optics algorithm first to group the code. Was it better or we should use the  Generalized Hough Transform that in here in the website. 
Sorry for dummy question, for now we just want an idea for the image processing techniques.
~bad english~

Comment: What is your question ? try and ask precise questions else it is difficult to answer.

Comment: What is the most used or efficient algorithm for this kind of app